# Convert Access queries to SQL Server views when using DTS

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, ms-access, import

I'm using DTS to import data from an Access database to SQL Server 2005. It seems that DTS imports Access queries as tables instead of views, which won't work for me. Is there any way around that?

Comment: Access queries allow features that cannot be converted to SQL Views, so you cannot always map them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose to not include the saved queries. (at least you can when using the SSMA  - I suggest you use this in place of DTS anyway…it tends to do a better job).

you can find it here:
http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/migration.aspx

It is not clear if you going to continue to use ms-access as the front end here or not?. If you plan to continue using access then you really don’t need to convert those saved queries (views) up to sql server anyway. Most of the saved queries in access will work as before (now with linked tables to sql server).

You only need change/fix those saved quires that run slow. In other words most queries can continue to be used and run as is. It is only the slow ones and especially the ones with aggregate  functions (sums, totals etc that process many records, but produce few rows). This types of queries really benefit from being moved up to sql server as a view (you then link to that view from ms-access).

If your not keeping any part of ms-access, then I am afraid there no automated tool for those queries.  In these cases I just do a cut + paste from ms-access right into the management studio view builder. Most queries require very little modifications.

Comment: My app supports several dbs, and access isn't technically one of them. I tried SSMA to do the whole import, but for some reason the app didn't work with the resulting db. So, I used DTS to do the tables and SSMA to do the queries (converted to views just fine) and it seems to work. Very weird.

Comment: @jobrahms: Access is not a database.

Comment: @David: If you believe that, then why do you say *"Specializing in implementing and supporting Jet Replication in Microsoft Access database applications"* on your profile web page?

Comment: @RedFilter: If I believe what?

Comment: @David: "Access is not a database"

Comment: What are you talkinb about? I could say "I specialize in implementing and supporting VB database applications" which means database applications that use VB as the front-end development platform. That's what "Access database applications" means. And that's not some uncommon interpretation of the phrase, but the way it's used in general. Given that Access is not a database, it's the only interpretation that makes any sense, and why you'd choose to interpret it nonsensically, I have no idea. Unless, of course, you just want to pick a fight.